# How can I show hidden files in my KDE Plasma Desktop's folder view?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, hidden-files

I'm using **`Kubuntu 16.04`** with its default `plasmashell 5.5.5`.

How can I show hidden files on my desktop?

The desktop can show `/home/user/Desktop` or other location and there is no setting for hidden files in *Folder View Settings* gui:

[image]

Comment: I do not think this is possible. It also defeats the purpose of having hidden files if they are viewable even on the "desktop view",

Comment: I am too busy for looking its codes. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Have you tried selecting folder view and using the keyboard shortcuts ALT+.

Comment: Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on Desktop
2. Unlock Widgets
3. Right-click again
4. Configure Desktop
5. Wallpaper tab
6. Layout: change from Desktop to Folderview

Comment: All icons are gone :D Did you mean Desktop to Folderview? My question is about  "How to show hidden files on Folderview" already :D